# Connection to the Web Socket

Tags: java, angular, spring, websocket, sockjs

I try to connect to web socket from angular to spring boot with SockJS:
I have errors after connection to the server's sockets :[image]

Spring Boot configuration:

```
 @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker( "/");
        config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/user");
        // config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/user");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new UserHandshakeHandler())
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> messageConverters) {
        DefaultContentTypeResolver resolver = new DefaultContentTypeResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        converter.setContentTypeResolver(resolver);
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        return false;
    }
```

Angular connection:

```
this.socket = new SockJS(environment.serverUrl + socketPrefix + '?token=' + this.authService.getAccessToken());
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(this.socket);
    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
      this.stompClient.subscribe(hubMethodSubscription.noteTextUpdate,
        (data: any) => { console.error(data); this.observableUpdateNoteText.next(JSON.parse(data.body)); });
      this.stompClient.subscribe(hubMethodSubscription.deleteNoteFromOwner,
        (data: any) => { console.error(data); this.observableDeleteNoteFromOwner.next(JSON.parse(data.body)); });
      this.stompClient.subscribe(hubMethodSubscription.sendNewNotificationKek,
        (data: any) => { console.error(data); });
    });
```

If I use WebSocket in front, I get incorrect working, where only first connection worked